# Are these mysql table index changes appropriate?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Because it takes forever to make index changes on my 40 million row table, I was hoping to get some feedback to make sure I do it right the first time.

Right now my "favorites" table has 3 indexes:

- Primary auto-increment index on (id)
- item_idx (item_id) - the id of the item that was favorited
- faver_id_idx (faver_profile_id, id) - for displaying favorites from a particular user starting with the most recent.

To check to see if the user has "faved" a particular item I use this query:

```
SELECT id FROM favorites 
WHERE item_id = '.mysql_real_escape_string($item_id).' 
AND faver_profile_id = '.mysql_real_escape_string($user['id']).' 
AND removed = 0
```

Which is doing an interect:

```
Using intersect(item_idx,faver_id_idx)
```

This seems pretty inefficient to me, so I'm considering the following index setup:

- Primary auto-increment index on (id)
- item_faver_idx (item_id, removed, faver_profile_id)
- faver_id_idx (faver_profile_id, removed, id)

The benefits I see are:

- I can check if a user has faved an item without doing an intersect or table sort.
- The "removed" (tinyint) column is now part of the index.

Questions I have:

- In the (item_id, removed, faver_profile_id) index is there any reason to have faver_profile_id come first instead? For instance, if I'm doing the following query..

  ```
  SELECT items.*, users.*, favorites.item_id 
  FROM items
  LEFT JOIN users ON (items.submitter_id = users.id) 
  LEFT JOIN favorites ON (items.id = favorites.item_id AND favorites.faver_profile_id = 56 AND favorites.removed = 0) 
  ORDER BY items.id desc LIMIT 26
  ```

  Would it be better to have faver_profile_id come first in the index so that it can just jump to the right faver_profile_id section of the index instead of having to check multiple item_id sections, and then scanning for the faver_profile_id within each of those sections?
- Does it make sense to have "removed" in the index if only 1-3% of rows have a removed value of 1? Basically, is a slightly more efficient table scan worth the extra index size?

Anything I'm overlooking?

Comment: Is this a MyISAM or an InnoDB table?

Comment: WHat other queries and statements do you run often against this table?

Comment: @ypercube: InnoDB and the only queries I run on the favorites table is one that grabs favorites from a particular faver_profile_id and orders by id desc, and the query I posted above that does the intersect.

Comment: So an index that has first part the `faver_profile_id` is needed. If you want to only serach for the `removed=0` items for a particular user, an index that starts with `(faver_profile_id, removed, ...)` would be good.

Comment: So, you might just need a `(faver_profile_id, removed, item_id)` index and these queries would be ok (no reading at all from the table, just the index).

Comment: Ah you're right, I've updated my post so that "removed" is the second column in my composite indexes. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do searches for items of a user or for users that have selected an item, regardless of whether items are removed or not, you'll need other indexes, though.

Comment: You may also consider dropping the `removed` column altogether after deleting all rows with `removed=1` or moving them into a separate table (and changing your update/insert statements accordingly).

Comment: I was under the impression that the primary key gaps caused by deleting "removed" rows could hurt performance.

Comment: You'll fragmentation in the table (and thus in the clustered index). How much, depends on how many rows you have deleted.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Do you know if it would it be any more efficient to have faver_profile_id first in the composite index for join queries like I described above?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7153/discussion-between-ypercube-and-makeee)